# remove onclick when attached to children

Tags: javascript, jquery, onclick

I have the following code:

```
layoutOverlaysBldg = $("#layout-overlays-bldg")
layoutOverlaysBldg.on("click", "div", function(event) {
  var floor;
  console.log("floornum: " + this.dataset.floornum);
  floor = parseInt(this.dataset.floornum);
  ...
  $("#choose-floor").fadeOut();
  $("#choose-apt").fadeIn();
});
```

later - based on data I'm getting back from the DB - I want to remove some of the `.on("click", "div", ...)` from only some of the divs. I already have the selector that is getting the right divs but I cannot figure out how to remove the click event. I have tried `.off("click")` after selecting the right div but it has no effect.

Comment: to unbind click you need to do unbind("click")

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This issue here is because you are using a delegated event. You can add or remove the event for all child elements, but not individual ones given your `div` selector.

With that in mind the easiest way to do what you need is to add the event based on a class, then add and remove that class on the children as needed. Something like this:

```
layoutOverlaysBldg = $("#layout-overlays-bldg")
layoutOverlaysBldg.on("click", "div.clickable", function(event) {
    // your code...
});
```

You can then enable/disable the event on the child div by adding or removing the `.clickable` class.

Comment: Sorry, it took a while for me to test it but this worked perfectly, and so simple.

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this :

Example :

```
     <div id="test">
        <div id="first">first</div>
        <div id="second">second</div>
     </div>

     <div onclick="unbindSecondDiv();">UNBIND</div>

    <script>
            function unbindSecondDiv()
            {
                test = $("#second")
                test.unbind("click");

                alert('Selected Area Click is Unbind');

            }

            $(document).ready(function(){
                    //BIND SELECTED DIV CLICK EVENT
                    test = $("#test > div")
                    test.bind("click" , function(event) {
                        alert($(this).attr('id'));
                    });
            });


    </script>
```

In the above example , selected DIV elements click event is bind.

And after execute function  unbindSecondDiv() , second DIV click event will be unbind.

Have a try , may helps you.